# Most of string gone after splitting with strtok?

Tags: c++, string, token, strtok

**e: Thanks everyone, didn't realize strtok actually modifies the string itself. Hopefully I'll be less stupid in the future.**

I have recently taken up learning C++ from a book. I am now at the chapter about parsing strings.

My next assignment is to put the tokens of a string back together after having split them with strtok, but I don't understand where the rest of the string has gone after the first delimiter! Keep in mind I am very new to this, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Basically what's happening is this:
1. I input a string "hey, how are you?"
2. Print it, comes out normal.
3. Then I split it into tokens (using delimiters , and space) 
4. They all print neatly
5. Print the string again and all that's left is "hey".

So how do I get the rest of the string back?

This is my code:

```
char the_string[ 81], *p;

cout << the_string << endl;

cout << "Input a string to parse: ";
cin.getline(the_string, 81);
p = strtok(the_string, ", ");
while (p != NULL) {
  cout << p << endl;
  p = strtok(NULL, ", ");
} 

cout << the_string << endl;
```

Comment: Try `man strtok` and get basic information.

Comment: Why not Zoidb...^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H `std::string` and `std::stringstream`?

Answer (score 4):

[`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) modifies the string on which it operates:

> If str != NULL, the function searches for the first character which is not separator. This character is the beginning of the token. Then the function searches for the first separator character. This character is the end of the token. Function terminates and returns NULL if end of str is encountered before end of the token is found. Otherwise, a pointer to end of the token is saved in a static location for subsequent invocations. **This character is then replaced by a NULL-character and the function returns a pointer to the beginning of the token.**

Make a copy of the string before passing to `strtok()`.

There are better ways to achieve this in C++ but as this sounds like homework you are probably not permitted to use them.

Answer (score 4):

`strtok()` changes the string it operates on by inserting a `'\0'` whenever it finds a token.

So, the string `"one two three\0"` (explicit `'\0'` for reference), when tokenised by space, gets changed to `"one\0two\0three\0"` and most string operation see it as `"one"` (I've removed the `'\0'` now)

Answer (score 0):

Next time you use a function, read its man page (more carefully). Strtok() tokenizes the string by replacing the first character of the delimiter with a null char. **Your string ends up being modified**. Something like this (\0 indicates a NUL char):

```
Hey\0 how\0 are\0 you?\0
```

Strdup() the string before passing it to strtok().

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation of strtok](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/strtok.html) states:

> The strtok() function then searches from there for a byte that is
>   contained in the current separator string. If no such byte is found,
>   the current token extends to the end of the string pointed to by s1,
>   and subsequent searches for a token shall return a null pointer. If
>   such a byte is found, **it is overwritten by a null byte**, which
>   terminates the current token. The strtok() function saves a pointer to
>   the following byte, from which the next search for a token shall
>   start.

So that means that when you print the string, the function for printing it stops after it gets past the first token and encounters the null character.  NULL usually means "end of string" for C strings.

Answer (score 0):

The way strtok() works is that it replaces the delimiter characters with the string end character. So "hey, how are you?" become "hey,\0how\0are\0you?"

This is one reason you usually shouldn't use strtok(). A second reason is that it works iteratively and stores information about the string for use in further calls to strtok(). If you use it from multiple threads that information gets overwritten and further calls won't work correctly.